# Batch variable inside of variable

Tags: batch-file, variables

- I've got a set of variables called p1 to p9
- I've got 2 vars to set the range I'm interested in.
- I want to list all the vars from minimum range +1 to the max.

It looks like that (and it won't work)

```
set currentvar=5
set maxvar=9
set p1=aaa
set p2=bbb
set p3=ccc
set p4=ddd
set p5=eee
set p6=fff
set p7=ggg
set p8=hhh
set p9=iii
set /a result = %maxvar% - %currentvar%
echo Found %result% vars in the range.
:LOOP
if %currentvar% LSS %maxvar% (
set /a currentvar=%currentvar% + 1
echo %p %currentvar% % //IT WON'T WORK AND I DON'T KNOW HOW TO MAKE IT WORK...
goto LOOP
) else (
goto END
)
:END
```

The result I'd like to see:

```
fff

ggg 

hhh

iii
```

Comment: you marked a non-working answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to `Enabledelayedexpansion`:

```
@echo off
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
set currentvar=5
set maxvar=9
set p1=aaa
set p2=bbb
set p3=ccc
set p4=ddd
set p5=eee
set p6=fff
set p7=ggg
set p8=hhh
set p9=iii
set /a result = %maxvar% - %currentvar%
echo Found %result% vars in the range.
:LOOP
if %currentvar% LSS %maxvar% (
set /a currentvar=%currentvar% + 1
echo !p%currentvar%! &REM This is how you make a comment in batch
goto LOOP
) else (
goto END
)
:END
Endlocal
```

And that should do what you want to do. Also to make a comment use a new line and type `::` or `REM`.

Mona

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't put any comments in batch in ages. I didn't knew that you can use ! to expand vars. That is exactly what I needed. You are awesome ;].

Comment: this doesn't work. Inside a code block you can't access changed `%variables%`, eg. `currentvar`  !

Answer (score 3):

this might work for you:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set /a currentvar=5
set /a maxvar=9
set /a RangeStart=currentvar+1
set p1=aaa
set p2=bbb
set p3=ccc
set p4=ddd
set p5=eee
set p6=fff
set p7=ggg
set p8=hhh
set p9=iii
set /a result=maxvar-currentvar
echo Found %result% vars in the range.
for /l %%a in (%RangeStart% 1 %maxvar%) do call echo(%%p%%a%%
```